# Why am I getting different outputs with .concat() and += with Java Strings?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

Studying for OCAJ7

I know String objects are immutable. I know using methods like `.concat()` on a String object will just create a new String object with the same reference name. I'm having a hard time, however, with wrapping my head around the following:

```
String str1 = "str1";
String str2 = "str2";
System.out.println( str1.concat(str2) );
System.out.println(str1);

// ouputs
// str1str2
// str1

String str3 = "fish";
str3 += "toad";
System.out.println(str3);

// outputs
// fishtoad
```

If strings are immutable, why does using `+=` to concatenate affect the original String object, but `.concat()` does not? If I only want a String to concatenate with using `+=`, is using `String` better than using `StringBuilder`, or vice versa?

Comment: Because `concat` doesn't assign the result of the concatenation to `str1`, it returns it.

Comment: Okay. If Strings are immutable, though, (because they use `char[]` and you can't just add more elements to an array), how can `str3` be changed using `+=`?

Comment: Because using `+=` creates a new instance of a String, which contains the concatenation of the 2 strings, and gives the reference to `str3`.

Comment: `str3 += "toad"` replaces the original string `str3` of "fish" with "fishtoad". concat() returns a new instance, so `str3 += "toad"` is similar to `str3 = str3.concat("toad");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you are catching the reference of newly generated String instance  in `str3`

```
str3 += "toad";
```

is

```
str3 = str3 + "toad"
```

Comment: So it's still creating a new String object and assigning it to `str3`?

Answer (score 1):

The [`concat` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat-java.lang.String-) is more like `+` than `+=`.  It returns the new string; it doesn't modify the original string or the argument (`String`s are immutable).

```
str1.concat(str2)
```

is equivalent to `str1 + str2`, so `str1` isn't modified, and the result is discarded.

However, `+=` also assigns the result back to the left side, and `str3` now refers to the new string.  That's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right Strings are immutable.

But when you write `str1.concat(str2)` inside System.out.println() you are printing the result returned by the concat() function.The result is a new String which is outputted on the console.
 You haven't assigned the value to `str1.`

But when you write `+=` you are first concatenating something to the String the then assigning the reference back to `str1`.

This explains the output.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that `String.concat(String);` does not actually combine `str1` and `str2` together, instead it returns a new String object that is equivalent to `str1str2`.  When you use `str1 += str2`, you are actually combining the variables, and then putting the value into `str1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
str3 += "toad" means
str3 = str3 + "toad";
```

So you concatenate  and assign the result back to str3

Answer (score 0):

concat() method creates a new string. You have to remember that Strings in Java are immutable.

str1 will point to the newly created string if the o/p is assigned to it,

```
str1 = str1.concat(str2);
```

otherwise str1 continues to point to the old string.

If you are going to concat multiple strings together in a loop, then it is better to use StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Above you are not changing the reference of `str1` in `System.out.println(str1.concat(str2) )` so it is temporary storing the reference of `str1.concat(str2)`.

But in `str3+=str4` whole reference get moved to "fishtoad" therefore it get changed.But again if you defined a string `str5="fish"` then it reference back to previous location which was referencing by `str3`.